# Is there a way to do something like SQL NOT top statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to make a SQL statement that gives me the top X records and then all sums all the others.  The first part is easy...

```
select top 3 Department, Sum(sales) as TotalSales
from Sales
group by Department
```

What would be nice is if I **union** a second query something like...

```
select NOT top 3 "Others" as Department, Sum(sales) as TotalSales
from Sales
group by Department
```

... for a result set that looks like,

```
Department    TotalSales
-----------   -----------
Mens Clothes  120.00
Jewelry       113.00
Shoes          98.00
Others        312.00
```

Is there a way to do an equivalent to a NOT operator on a TOP?  (I know I can probably make a temp table of the top X and work with that, but I'd prefer a solution that was just a single sql statement.)

Comment: Lots of good answers.  I was thrown for a loop by all the WITH keywords as I'd never seen it before.  Sadly, I'm stuck with using SQL 2000.  I would have included it in my question had I know it was a factor. I've upvoted all the appropriate answers as they supplied valid solutions for most people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sales) DESC) rn,
                CASE
                WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(sales) DESC) <= 3 THEN
                        department
                ELSE
                        'Others'
                END AS dept,
                SUM(sales) AS sales
        FROM    sales
        GROUP BY
                department
        )
SELECT  dept, SUM(sales)
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        dept
ORDER BY
        MAX(rn)
```

Comment: +1 'cause @Martin liked it... but how to set ORDER BY such that "Others" ends up as the last row?

Comment: @Philip Kelley: Add `order by case when Dept <> 'Others' then SUM(sales) end desc`

Comment: I marked this as the answer since the community upvoted it the most. I actually went with a different solution because I'm using an old version of SQL server... but clearly this answer will work best for most other people looking up the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH cte
     As (SELECT Department,
                Sum(sales) as TotalSales
         from   Sales
         group  by Department),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT *,
                CASE
                  WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalSales DESC) <= 3 THEN
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalSales DESC)
                  ELSE 4
                END AS Grp
         FROM   cte)
SELECT MAX(CASE
             WHEN Grp = 4 THEN 'Others'
             ELSE Department
           END)        AS Department,
       SUM(TotalSales) AS TotalSales
FROM   cte2
GROUP  BY Grp
ORDER  BY Grp
```

Comment: I'm always amazed at how quickly Martin can bust out these queries.  If he's online, I don't even bother trying to answer these questions... he'll beat me to it by about 5 minutes with a much better query than the one I was writing.

Comment: @mfredrickson - But then Quassnoi comes in with a simpler one!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a union to sum all other departments.  A common table expression makes this a little bit more readable:

```
; with Top3Sales as
        (
        select  top 3 Department
        ,       Sum(sales) as TotalSales
        from    Sales
        group by 
                Department
        order by 
                Sum(sales) desc
        )
select  Department
,       TotalSales
from    Top3Sales
union all
select  'Other'
,       SUM(Sales)
from    Sales
where   Department not in (select Department from Top3Sales)
```

[Example at data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/95921/).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 3 Department, SUM(Sales) AS TotalSales
FROM   Sales
GROUP BY Department
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Others', SUM(s.Sales)
FROM   Sales s
WHERE  s.Department NOT IN
       (SELECT Department
        FROM   (SELECT TOP 3 Department, SUM(Sales)
                FROM   Sales
                GROUP BY Department) D)
```

Comment: This is nice because it works in earlier versions of sql server.